# Bash search string issues

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

I am trying to lint specific files on git precommit. I am making a bash script to do this only on affected files. I am having an issue with filtering out files that are not in specific directories.

Here is my script:

```
# Load modified files of the current PR
declare -a modifiedFiles=$(git diff --name-status | cut -f2)

declare -a projectsList=$(find . -name *project.json -exec realpath {} \; | xargs cat | jq '.name')

for fileName in ${modifiedFiles[@]}; do
    STR="$fileName"
    SUB="apps/${projectName:0:5}"
    if grep -q "$SUB" <<< "$STR"; then
        echo "Run my linting script"
        break
    fi
done
```

The general idea is I am getting the 'name' of each project in my directory by searching the 'project.json' file for the 'name' parameter. I am getting the list of modified files from GIT.

Once I have those I want to only run linting on files that are in a 'project' directory and that are typescript files.

I can get my lists but I cannot get the if statement to work using the elements from those arrays

Comment: `-name *project.json` has unpredictable behavior depending on the files in your current directory. Quote your globs: `-name "*project.json"` -- that way you don't risk the shell replacing `-name *project.json` with `-name myproject.json theirproject.json` before `find` even starts.

Comment: Beyond that, `declare -a array=$(anything)` only assigns `array[0]`. It needs to be `declare -a array=( $(anything) )` to word-split, but even that is buggy for the reasons described in [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29); better to use `readarray -d $'\n' array < <(...cmd...)` for a command that emits line-oriented content, or better, to use commands that emit NUL-delimited output and use `readarray -d ''`

Comment: BTW, what's the point of piping output from `realpath` into `xargs cat`? Why not just `-exec cat -- {} +`, or even simpler, `-exec jq '.name' -- {} +` and avoid running _either_ `realpath` or `cat` in the first place?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the comments. I am sorry I am not sure how to implement your advice about xargs.

Do you mean:
`declare -a projectsList=$(find . -name *project.json -exec  jq '.name' -- {} +)`

Comment: Again, `declare -a projectsList=$(anything)` is broken. Don't do that. It only looks like it works here because you're using `${projectsList}` instead of `"${projectsList[@]}"` (or really, in the code given, not using `projectsList` at all); but as soon as your code is correctly quoted it'll act like the whole list is one big string (because it is).

Comment: `mapfile -t projectsList < <(find . -name '*project.json' -exec jq -r '.name' -- {} +)` is somewhat better. Note the `-r` to tell jq not to add literal quotes but instead print the strings themselves as opposed to the JSON escaping of those strings. (Also note the quotes added around the `*project.json` glob).

Comment: okay  @CharlesDuffy so this helps but it does not resolve my issue that I cannot get the if statement to compare the strings

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question with feedback from @CharlesDuffy

```
# Load modified files of the current PR
declare -a modifiedFiles=$(git diff --name-status | cut -f2)

for fileName in ${modifiedFiles[@]}; do
    if [[ $fileName = *.ts]]; then
        echo "Run my linting script"
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: The `declare -a` does absolutely nothing here: you aren't actually splitting the results of `git diff` into separate array entries. The only reason it _looks_ like it works is because you also aren't quoting `"${modifiedFiles[@]}"`, so the single array entry gets split into multiple words later, by the unquoted expansion. This will cause bugs as soon as you have filenames with whitespace, or _especially_ filenames combining whitespace and glob characters (say, if someone runs `touch 'hello * world.ts'`)

Comment: As a more minor typo thing, you also want a space before the `]]`.